# Binding Parameter Must Be list While Using Python Snowflake Connector

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Python SNowflake  Connector 2.4.1 to connect Python to Snowflake
getting following error

"Binding Parameter Must Be list While Using Python Snowflake Connector"

I am Binding Sample_JSON String Containing JSON to SQL Query String Using Qmark
, The Table Column is VARIANT type in Snowflake

```
Sample_JSON="{\"ABC\":\"VALUE\"}"
snowflake.connector.paramstyle='qmark'
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='something.com',,
      account=  'something',
    authenticator='externalbrowser'
    )

cs = ctx.cursor()

try:
       
cs.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (JOSN) VALUES(?)",(Sample_JSON) )

finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at this [execute many example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#executemany)

```
# A list of lists
sequence_of_parameters1 = [ ['Smith', 'Ann'], ['Jones', 'Ed'] ]
# A tuple of tuples
sequence_of_parameters2 = ( ('Cho', 'Kim'), ('Cooper', 'Pat') )

stmt2 = "insert into testy (v1, v2) values (?, ?)"
cs.executemany(stmt2, sequence_of_parameters1)
cs.executemany(stmt2, sequence_of_parameters2)
```

it would imply your code should be:

```
cs.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (JOSN) VALUES(?)",( (Sample_JSON) ) )
```

or:

```
cs.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (JOSN) VALUES(?)",[ [Sample_JSON] ] )
```

Comment: Hi @Simeon Pilgrim thanks for answer the second option worked for me cs.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (JOSN) VALUES(?)",[ [Sample_JSON] ] )  , thanks gain for your timely help